# unable to import pyodbc module in python azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, pyodbc

I'm writing a python azure function. For simplicity, I'm using the sample python function like below.

I developed the function in my vscode and tried to test it on my local machine. The azure function failed start. It throw the error saying  `failed to import pyodbc`.

However, there is no issue when I change `import pyodbc` to `import pandas` or other modules like sklearn, numpy, etc. So I'm pretty sure the issue is from module pyodbc.

Does anyone have the same issue? How to solve this? I have no clue... Thanks a lot.

Here is the azure function:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

# it works when I import other modules like pandas, sklearn, etc
import pyodbc


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
            status_code=400
        )
```

here is my requirement.txt

```
azure-functions
pyodbc
#pandas
#numpy
#sklearn
```

Comment: Hi zesla, have you installed the pyodbc module successfully ? Could you please check if it exists in ".venv" --> "Lib" --> "site-packages" ?

Comment: There is a folder call `pyodbc-4.0.28.dist-info`, but no folder called `pyodbc`

Comment: interestingly I was able to `import pypyodbc`. I can use it as a workaround. but why `import pyodbc` not working? so weird!

Comment: It's really strange, may I know the version of your python ?

Comment: @Hury Shen     my python version is 3.7.5    Maybe because of python version?

Comment: Hi zesla, my python version is 3.6.8, it works fine. And I installed python 3.7.5 just now and test on it(also install and import pypyodbc, pandas, numpy and sklearn), they all work fine. So it could be a very small area that's not configured properly in your environment, do you still want to use pyodbc ? or just use pypyodbc as workaround ?

Comment: By the way, if you still want to use pyodbc, you can have a try to install the lower version of pyodbc. Currently the latest version is 4.0.28, you can try to install the version 4.0.27 and import it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the answer from the OP's comments as a workaround:

> interestingly I was able to import pypyodbc. I can use it as a workaround

Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59652163/how-to-fix-import-pyodbc-which-fails-with-error) with similar problem which was solved by installing a lower version of "pyodbc" for others reference.